# String class final field VS single String variable in code

Tags: java, string, field, final

Is using more than once the same String value in class methods always means creating constant field in class? Two examples:

**Approach #1: Field**

```
private static final String PROP_NAME = "prop.name";
```

and usage:

```
private String getPropertyNameValue(){
  return propService.getProperty(PROP_NAME);
}
```

**Approach #2: Without field**

```
private String getPropertyNameValue(){
  return propService.getProperty("prop.name");
}
```

Which way is better? If the manner of using them is equals - what are pros and cons of each?

**Thanks.**

Comment: Primarily opinion based, but my 2c: if it's used in multiple places, use the constant. If it's used in just that place, use the literal (you're just introducing indirection otherwise; having to look in two places to find out which property is returned is extra cognitive load).

Comment: @michal : private static final String PROP_NAME = "prop.name";
Declaring variable as static final will help you to create a CONSTANT, Only one copy exists which can be accessed anywhere.
So if you want a constant PROP_NAME and want share in mutltiplce (with in class or out side of class) then you should go with static final.